# Getting Top 5 objects in array with highest value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need help to make the following possible, I have an array of objects and I want to extract the TOP 5 objects with the best value of return and in order from best to worst. How could I do it?

Heres how my array looks like:

```
const Top5ReturnsArray = [
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 1'}, return: 3.0 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 2'}, return: 1.4 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 3'}, return: -2.6 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 4'}, return: -4.5 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 4'}, return: 4.0 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 5'}, return: 2.3 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 6'}, return: -7.3 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 7'}, return: 3.5 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 8'}, return: -0.4 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 9'}, return: -0.8 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 10'}, return: -1.0 }
]
```

Comment: See [`array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the array in descending order, then use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the first 5 elements.

```js
const arr = [
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 1'}, return: 3.0 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 2'}, return: 1.4 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 3'}, return: -2.6 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 4'}, return: -4.5 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 4'}, return: 4.0 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 5'}, return: 2.3 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 6'}, return: -7.3 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 7'}, return: 3.5 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 8'}, return: -0.4 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 9'}, return: -0.8 },
    { signalInfo: { signalName: 'Signal 10'}, return: -1.0 }
];
let res = [...arr].sort((a, b) => b.return - a.return).slice(0, 5);
console.log(res);
```